# How to access a module in source-files inside a custom webpack plugin?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-plugin

## A very simple project:

- Entry file is `index.js`
- One module `foo.js`
- `index.js` *imports* `foo.js`
- A basic `webpack.config.js`
- One custom plugin - `HelloWorldPlugin`

## Files:

```
// ./src/foo.js
export default {
  foo: 'foo'
}
```

---

```
// ./src/index.js
import foo from './foo'
console.log(foo);
```

---

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
var HelloWorldPlugin = require('./hello-world-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  plugins: [
    new HelloWorldPlugin({ options: true })
  ]
};
```

---

```
// HelloWorldPlugin.js
class HelloWorldPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tapAsync("HelloWorldPlugin", (compilation, next) => {
      console.log(arguments);
      // let foo = the module as imported from ./src/foo.js i.e. {foo: 'foo'}
      next();
    });
  }
}

module.exports = HelloWorldPlugin;
```

## Question is:

Is it possible to access `{foo:'foo'}` from the `foo-module` inside `HelloWorldPlugin`?

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to get the source code in your plugin, you can get it from `compilation.assets[fileName].source()`, and you can do that:

```
class HelloWorldPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tapAsync("HelloWorldPlugin", (compilation, next) => {
      console.log(arguments);
      compilation.hooks.afterOptimizeAssets.tap({ name: 'name' }, (modules) => {
        for (let fileName in modules) {
          const source = compilation.assets[fileName].source();
          console.log(source); // source of files
        }
      })
      next();
    });
  }
}
```

by hooking into one of `compilation` [hooks](https://webpack.js.org/api/compilation-hooks/) you can access all your modules and get filenames and their content

Comment: Hi @d7my, thank you for your response.  I want to access the `Object - { foo: 'foo'}` inside the plugin.  Also, the `afterOptimizeAssets hook` did not trigger on the build so the `console.log` did not execute.